# Question about jQuery DatePicker Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a question reguards to the jQuery DatePicker Plugin.

I know there is something called AltField.

I have a date range function, which is just the demo codes.

The code is here

```
    $(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

My question is how to apply two different AltField for each of the input field?

Thanks a lot.

I spent whole afternoon already and still get any clue...

Answer (score 2):

`altField` (note the lower-case "a", as you have used an upper-case "A" in your question) is just another option the `datepicker` function takes in it's options object argument (just like `defaultDate` and `changeMonth` for example, as you're already using them). Therefore, you can add it in just like those (`altField` is a property of the options object; it's value should be a selector string):

```
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
    altField: "#someOtherField",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings );
        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
    }
});
```

The above example would use whatever matches the selector `#someOtherField` as the `altField`. This goes hand-in-hand with the `altFormat` option, which allows you to specify the format of the value in the alternate field. For more information, just [read the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altField).

Comment: Hi, I can use one ALTField easily in this situation. However, the question is how to use TWO ALTFIELDS.

Comment: @mu is too short - That's because the `onSelect` handler is interfering: http://jsfiddle.net/8YS3g/2/

Comment: @user361022 - That wasn't your question... your question makes no mention of multiple `altField`s!

Comment: I just updated my question. I want to have two different altfield. When I click on the "From" textbox,after select the date, the altfieid1 will get the altFormatted data from the first datepicker. When I click on the "To" textbox, after select the date, the altField2 will get the altFormatted date from the second datepicker.

Comment: @user361022: If you want two `altField`s then you'd bind your datepickers separately. You could put the options in an object and then `$.extend({}, opts, { altField: ... })` to build your datepicker options if you don't want to repeat yourself. Or just use the `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altField", '#actualDate' );` example from the docs to set the `altField` options after binding the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

AltField allows you to update another text input with the datepicker value.
Add `altField: '#actualDate',` to the init string, after numberOfMonths, before onSelect
Where #actualDate is the id of another text input

```
<input type="text" id="actualDate" />
```